# How to convert MySQL query into GORM query

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two tables: `users` and `jobs` where each user can have multiple jobs, but one specific job belongs to one user.

```
type Job struct {
    ID      uint   `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    Title   string `gorm:"type:varchar(255); not null" json:"title"`
    Content string `gorm:"not null" json:"content"`
    UserID  uint   `json:"-"`
}

type User struct {
    ID         uint      `gorm:"primarykey" json:"-"`
    UUID       uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:char(36) not null" json:"-"`
    Name       string    `gorm:"type:varchar(255); not null" json:"name"`
    Jobs       []Job     `json:"-"`
}
```

I want to get every single post with its author.

The following query works:

```
SELECT j.id, j.title, j.content, u.name AS author
FROM jobs AS j
INNER JOIN users AS u
ON j.user_id = u.id
```

In Gorm:

```
func (jobRepo repository) FindAll() []entity.Job {
    var jobs []entity.Job
    jobRepo.db.Find(&jobs)

    // how do we handle the rest?

    return jobs
}
```

I have to return the following JSON response:

```
job_id: <random_id>
job_title: "Test Title Content",
job_content: "Test Job Content",
author: {
  name: "Test User Name"
}
```

How can I get author's data for each post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JSON response you need to generate, you might start by adding  the `User` field to the `Job` struct like this:

```
type Job struct {
    ID      uint   `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    Title   string `gorm:"type:varchar(255); not null" json:"title"`
    Content string `gorm:"not null" json:"content"`
    UserID  uint   `json:"-"`
    User    User   `json:"author"`
}
```

Also, just a small change is needed in your repo method to load this. I've added error checks because you should have them always.

```
func (jobRepo repository) FindAll() ([]entity.Job, error) {
    var jobs []entity.Job
    tx := jobRepo.db.Preload("User").Find(&jobs)

    return jobs, tx.Error
}
```